# What is the difference between these two words 叫做 and 叫作?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, usage

What is the difference between these two words 叫做 and 叫作? The dictionary definition is quite similar and when I use this term in conversation I am unaware of which character combination I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have same meaning, same usage and same pronunciation, basically you don't need to figure out them consciously especially in spoken Chinese.

> 但实际上两者并没有什么区别，也就是说“叫作”同“叫做”，而“叫做”同“叫作”。

And here're some more clarifications; it seems 叫做 is the standard usage formerly, but 叫作 is recommended more now.

> 而我又翻看了现在的一些教材，发现现在版本教材上写的都是“叫作”。
>
> 上网查了下之后，发现2011年时全国科学技术名词审定委会和国家语言文字工作委员会推荐的是使用“叫作”。
>
> 而《现代汉语规范词典》每一版对于“叫作”和“叫做”的记载也都不同。
>
> [image: 现代汉语3/5/6版本的不同解释]
>
> 在大体上理解，曾经是以“叫做”为标准，但是现在更推荐的都是“叫作”。
>
> 简单的说这俩词是互用互通的，而也有些资料上显示“叫作”本身就是错误用法，但现在与“叫做”混用。

Reference: [叫做还是叫作？](https://www.bilibili.com/read/cv125296/)

Comment: This answer seems rather incomplete, but the references you've given are useful. Traditionally 叫做 has been the correct form, but 叫作 might be shifting into standard usage. There doesn't seem to be a lot of consensus...

Comment: Actually there is some what of a consensus. 规范词典：现在一般写作“叫做”。

Comment: Both links are broken to me.

Comment: @scaaahu Sadly I can't find them back.. I refactored the answer.

Answer (score 3):

叫做 is more casual and 叫作 is less casual. Usually in Cantonese Chinese, we use 叫作 in writing and 叫做 in speaking.

Answer (score 0):

My wife - native Chinese speaker - thinks 叫作 is the correct way to write this even though 叫做 translated literally has the same meaning.